# Qt draw lines without fill but edge lines

Tags: qt, paint

I am trying to draw wide lines like(50 pixel wide) on screen with transparent filling and solid colored edge lines.

Transparent fill with solid edge lines

[image]

Any suggestions on how to implement this in Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- create a `QPainterPath`
- add the desired shapes to it, like `QPainterPath::addRoundedRect()`
- use `QPainter::strokePath(yourpath, yourpen)` to draw just the outline